# Translations of menu items aren't work after update Joomla to version 3.7.0

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, translation

I have problem with translations of menu items after update Joomla to version 3.7.0. This website has 7 language versions. Other translations works, eg. k2_items or articles. Only menu items aren't translated.

I'm using *gk_news2* template made by GavickPro.

Przemek

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Interestingly, on one site it works fine, on another it doesn't. Only the one that works has K2, the other is a very basic site, using Protostar standard template.